# Refresh Windows after changing mouse settings through registry

Tags: c++, windows, qt

I wrote a small application to change my mouse settings.

The problem is that they don't apply when I change the registry, instead they apply after I either logout and login or reboot.

The prototype code:

```
QSettings settings("HKEY_CURRENT_USER\\Control Panel\\Mouse", QSettings::NativeFormat);
QVariant value("10");
settings.setValue("MouseSensitivity", value);
```

How can I make the changes take effect immediately?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need immediate action, you need to use
`SystemParametersInfo` API with `SPI_SETMOUSESPEED` parameter:

```
int mouseParams[3];
mouseParams[2] = NewmouseAccel;
SystemParametersInfo(SPI_SETMOUSE, 0, mouseParams, SPIF_SENDCHANGE);
```

Also it's more professional way, instead of using registry trick.

Comment: Thanks!

Though, for changing the mouse speed SPI_SETMOUSE is not the correct function. Using these parameters works.

`SystemParametersInfo(SPI_SETMOUSESPEED, 0, (int *) value, SPIF_SENDCHANGE);`

Source for parameters: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724947%28v=vs.85%29.aspx